# ProcessBuilder with open command fails on OSX

Tags: java, macos, processbuilder, auto-update

I am encountering a problem related to macOS.
To explain the case, we try to update an old auto-update system for mac that just replaced the old jar files, with a new code that will automatically open a .pkg installer file after his download. (the only way for us to update all the application, using Sparkle or other framework is not possible at this stage).

The .pkg file is signed with an "Developer ID Installer ID" certificate.
The .app file is signed with an "Developer ID Application ID" certificate.

But...
When application is launched by double clicking it, or from the terminal with an "open" command, when it comes to the part of code where we try to launch the pkg via a ProcessBuilder and the "open" command, nothing happens, and the Apple console app says that a security issue occured (-67062), nothing more.

However, when the same Application is launched directly via the java command determined by the JavaApplicationStub (copy pasted from the Apple Console Application log), it works without any problem, and the pkg opens fine.

What could we do to overcome this one?

**UPDATE:**
I also discovered that the command 'spctl -a -v" returns :

```
 MyApp.pkg: rejected
 source=no usable signature
```

Unless it is used with the parameter "--type install" which gives:

```
 MyApp.pkg: accepted
 source=Developer ID
```

I don't know if it matters or if it the expected result but it may help

**UPDATE 2 :**

Digging further in High Sierra logs (not accessible with the Console, although it seemed provided for that...), with the following command :

```
 log stream --debug
```

I was able to see that the issue came from the jspawnhelper file located in the "lib" folder of the JRE, that was not signed by Oracle...
By the way, this means that we must include a JRE bundled with a Java app, with all executable properly signed with a "Developer ID Application" certificate.

But...still not solved...
Another error occurs, again with the "open" command, but it goes a little further.
Now I have the following, thrown by the builtin Installer.app from Apple :

```
 No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting.
```

And still no idea, as my package already contains an Info.plist...